# backbone extension file loads, some helpers work, one doesn't

Tags: backbone.js, extend, backbone-views, extending

I have a backbone-extend.js file that I load in the require define in app.js. It has a Backbone.View extender class defining a couple helper methods. Two of the methods work just fine in my views, one always errors with `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'gotoUrl'`. Why would just this one method be not defined but the other two are working fine? Do you see any issue in this code...

```
// Filename: backbone-extend.js

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone) {

    var helpers = {
        eventSyncError: function(model,response,options) {
            console.log('Sync error='+response.statusText);
            $('#server-message').css({'color':'red', 'font-weight':'bold'}).text(response.statusText);
        },

        gotoUrl: function(url,delay) {
            var to = setTimeout(function() { Backbone.history.navigate(url, true); }, delay);
        },

        getFormData: function(form) { 
            var unindexed_array = form.serializeArray();
            var indexed_array = {};

            $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i) {
                indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
            });

            return indexed_array;
        }
    }

    _.extend(Backbone.View.prototype, helpers);

});
```

Here is the code in view that calls it...

```
    eventSyncMemberSaved: function(model,response,options) {
        console.log("Member saved!");
        $('#server-message').css({'color':'green', 'font-weight':'bold'}).text("Member saved!");
        this.gotoUrl('members',2000);
        //setTimeout(function() { Backbone.history.navigate('members', true); }, 2000);
    },

    saveMember: function() {
        var data = this.getFormData($('#member-form'));
        this.member.save(data, { success: this.eventSyncMemberSaved });
    },
```

Thanks in advance for your help. I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you also post the example of where you are calling it. It does not make sense without the context

Comment: @Sushanth--: Added a bit of the view code showing the helper method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context of **`this`** is different in the `success callback.`

It no longer **points to the view** as it points to the `xhr` object

So it throws an error as that  method is not available on the `xhr` object

To resolve it you need to bind the `context` of this to the success handler so that it points to the right object.

So in the initialize of the view add this code

```
initialize: function() {

    _.bindAll(this, 'eventSyncMemberSaved');
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks Sushanth. However, looking at this I'm thinking its ugly code. Perhaps I should rethink where some of the 'helper' methods live. Maybe a Helper class with static methods.

Comment: @Locohost.. Glad to have helped :) You can do that as well.. Depends upon how you feel comfortable with it